# MS.ACCESS - Loop trough records for mass print - Error item not found

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to put together a quick way of sending multiple records for print in one go..

To achieve it I put together a query [Qry_Mass_Print] rounding up job card numbers [Job Number] with a yes/no field indicating if the record should be printed [PrntJbSwtch]

In VBA using the watch list the below code appears to be counting the correct number of records so I believe the look up is working but I can't seem to extract the job number while looping through to assign to the print string variable PRNTstr

```
Private Sub MssJbCrdPrnt_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim PRNTstr As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset


strSQL = "SELECT 'Job Number' FROM Qry_Mass_Print WHERE [PrntJbSwtch] = True"
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
With rs
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
        While (Not .EOF)
       '' MsgBox (!Job_Number)
          PRNTstr = !Job_Number
           DoCmd.OpenReport "JobCard", acNormal, , PRNTstr
            .MoveNext
        Wend
End If
            .Close
End With

ExitSub:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume ExitSub
    
End Sub
```

I think its the retrieving the Job Number causing the issue as I can't even get it to show in a msgBox...

Any suggestions on what's causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the SQL string being:

```
strSQL = "SELECT 'Job Number' FROM Qry_Mass_Print WHERE [PrntJbSwtch] = True"
```

You should wrap the field name in square brackets:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Job Number] FROM Qry_Mass_Print WHERE [PrntJbSwtch] = True"
```

You may also want to put an `ORDER BY` in the SQL string.

.. and to adjust the code accordingly:

```
PRNTstr = ![Job Number].Value
```

Regards,

Comment: Brilliant... Thats got it working!..... There was one other small error in there and it was also all my lack of talent... the PRNTstr should of also referneced the filter it was going to so should of read .. PRNTstr = "[Job Number] =" & ![Job Number].Value .... if not you it send the whole data base worth of records #whoops... Thanks guys.!